# Sending my own ARP packet using SharpPcap and Packet.Net

Tags: c#, sharppcap, packet.net

I am trying unsuccessfully so far to send an ARP packet I have created with Packet.Net using SharpPcap. The problem is even though I send the packet using `device.SendPacket` it doesn't actually get sent, and I have no idea why.

This is my code:

```
ARPPacket arpPacket = new ARPPacket(ARPOperation.Request, PhysicalAddress.Parse("000000000000"), targetIpAddress, device.Interface.MacAddress, myIpAddress);
EthernetPacket ethPacket = new EthernetPacket(device.Interface.MacAddress, PhysicalAddress.Parse("FFFFFFFFFFFF"), EthernetPacketType.Arp);
ethPacket.PayloadPacket = arpPacket;
device.Open();
device.SendPacket(ethPacket);
device.Close();
```

By the way, it is important that I send my own ARP packets and not just use the SharpPcap ARP class.

Comment: Have you used Wireshark on the sending computer to see what packet is being sent? Have you tried using Pcap.Net (if not, why did you tag this question with Pcap.Net)?

Comment: Yes I have used Wireshark and filtering for 'arp' I didn't find my packet. The Pcap.Net tag was by mistake (meant it to be a Packet.Net tag, changed it now), and if I won't find a solution I will use Pcap.Net, but I like Packet.Net and SharpPcap much more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static void ARP(IPAddress ipAddress , LivePcapDevice device)
{
if (ipAddress == null )
throw new Exception("ARP IP address Cannot be null");
var ethernetPacket = new PacketDotNet.EthernetPacket(device.Addresses[1].Addr.hardwareAddress, PhysicalAddress.Parse("FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF"), PacketDotNet.EthernetPacketType.Arp);

var arpPacket = new PacketDotNet.ARPPacket(PacketDotNet.ARPOperation.Request, PhysicalAddress.Parse("00-00-00-00-00-00"), ipAddress , device.Addresses[1].Addr.hardwareAddress, device.Addresses[0].Addr.ipAddress );
ethernetPacket.PayloadPacket = arpPacket;

device.SendPacket(ethernetPacket);
}
```

Try this function, from: http://stolenpackets.net/?p=29

Comment: WOW! I almost gave up on using SharpPcap but this actually works! Although I have no idea why this code works and mine doesn't, but I will look into that. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: PhysicalAddress.Parse("FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF") was the missing magic 

Answer (score 2):

looking at [this code](http://www.codeforge.com/read/120870/ARP.cs__html) there is no ethernetpacket involved

```
ARPPacket arpPacket = new ARPPacket(ARPOperation.Request, PhysicalAddress.Parse("000000000000"), targetIpAddress, device.Interface.MacAddress, myIpAddress);
arpPacket.ARPTargetProtoAddress = destIP;
arpPacket.DestinationHwAddress = PhysicalAddress.Parse("FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF");
device.Open();
device.SendPacket(arpPacket);
device.Close();
```

Comment: Tells me that "'PacketDotNet.ARPPacket' does not contain a definition for 'ARPTargetProtoAddress'" and same with 'DestinationHwAddress'. Probably because the code in your link is from SharpPcap version 2.1.2 while I am using the latest version which is 4.1.0.